# How to check address is correct or not in Android?

Tags: android, street-address

I am creating an application in Android where I ask user to enter his address.There are chances that a user can enter wrong address so how can I check that the entered address is correct or not.

Please Help

Comment: How do you define a "wrong" address and a "correct" address?  If the "correct" address is "123 Main Street", would "125 Main street" be "wrong"?  Also, are you talking about specific countries? Specific address formats, etc.?  What about incomplete addresses, e.g. "Main Street, City, Country" - with missing post code?

Comment: @AleksG  , is there any such way? as i know we get the location in a map by geocoding/reverse geocoding... but to check actual address we can store the map coordinates in a local server and match according to that.It will be helpful if you say.. i really donot know it well except a few functionalities

Comment: What you are looking for is simply not possible.

Comment: @divaNilisha I don't think it's possible.  It would be very nice if it were, but no such luck

Answer (score 0):

You could show this address on the map and ask the user to confirm it's correct. Simple example:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("geo:0,0?q=my+street+address");
var mapIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, geouri);
startActivity (mapIntent);
```